# Rewriting natural log question

Tags: integration, logarithms

Can I rewrite $x \ln(x^2)$ as $2x \ln x$? Does this make sense?

Because I know $\ln(x^2)$ can be rewritten as $2\ln(x)$. So I figured $$x \times2\ln(x) =2x\ln(x)$$. I am trying to integrate the original $x\times \ln(x^2)$ using integration by parts, but I tried to simplify first, but it doesn't give me the right answer, off by a $\frac{1}{2}$ apparently.

Comment: Yes you can - this is a valid move.

Comment: Well $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(|x|)$ also if the integral is off by $1/2$ it may be just the constant that is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. But if you want integrate the function $f(x)=x\ln (x^2)$  I suggest the substitution 
$$
x^2=u \quad \rightarrow  \quad  2x dx=du
$$